# How to catch this PHP/Magento error: when no thumbnail, code breaks

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom Point of Sale admin Magento extension. I’m trying to add a thumbnail to the admin product grid on the POS page. It works 100% fine when there is a thumbnail image for every product. But when there’s a product without an image, the code totally breaks.

How do I modify this code to check whether there’s a thumbnail, and if not, to display a placeholder (any substitute html is fine)?

```
<?php

  class MDN_PointOfSales_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Thumbnail
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
  {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {      

    $cProduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
    $cProductId = $row->getId();
    $cProduct->load($cProductId);  // works for product IDs w/ a thumbnail. Breaks if no thumbnail set.
    // For example, the following line works, loading the thumbnail for the 5533 product for all rows in the grid:  
    // $cProduct->load(5533);

    $cMyUrl = $cProduct->getThumbnailUrl();

    $html = '<img ';
    $html .= 'src="' . $cMyUrl . '"';
    $html .= 'class="grid-image ' . $cProductId . '"/>';

    return $html;      

    }
  }
?>
```

Whole page results in an error if there’s no thumbnail:
http://www.screencast.com/t/zk6jVChiAC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wrap the call that triggers the exception in a try catch block and put code in to do the placeholder:

```
try {
    $cMyUrl = $cProduct->getThumbnailUrl();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Do something here
}
```

But don't. This is simply masking the underlying problem:

The placeholder image is missing from both /skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/images/catalog/product/placeholder and the theme it inherits from

You can see the exception being thrown (and the reason: no image and no placeholder) in: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php` in the `setBaseFile()` method.

I would rather let Magento handle the placeholders properly, rather than let that exception be thrown unnecessarily and have to code around it.

So, add your placeholder images to the skin images directories mentioned above - you should have the following:

```
/skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg
/skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
/skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg
```

or at least some in the base theme

```
/skin/frontend/base/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg
/skin/frontend/base/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
/skin/frontend/base/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg
```

Comment: Yes! That worked. What threw me off was that I had all those placeholder images in the proper directories listed above, so I thought the error was elsewhere. But the issue was that my placeholder thumbnails were somehow un-set in the admin (showing a missing image). Probably lost during my upgrade from 1.4 to 1.6. So, in the admin > configuration > catalog > Product Image Placeholders, I re-uploaded the placeholder images, specifically the thumbnail, and it worked. The placeholder images were showing up fine in the frontend, but not here in admin configuration.

Comment: So, your placeholder image solution worked... but given Magento can unnset these images (for whatever reasons and whatever circumstances), I will also use the error catching code since that worked as well, in case these thumbnails are ever missing in the future.

Answer (score -1):

The exception is thrown in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::setBaseFile($file) while the catalog/image helper tries to initialize the gallery and load the thumbnail.
This happens when you try to get the thumbnail url, not when you load the product.

The easiest way to avoid this is to catch the exception by using

```
try {
    $cMyUrl = $cProduct->getThumbnailUrl();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $cMyUrl = 'default_thumbnail.jpg'; // or something else ;-)
}
```